# Android Multiple Level JsonObject and JsonArray Parsing with Model class

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

```
{
"Query":"query",
"KMAQuery":"query",
"TotalCount":3,
"Data":[{"CollName":"kmdb_new",
         "TotalCount":3,
         "Count":3,
         "Result":[{"title":"sampletitle",
                    "director":[{"directorNm":"name1","directorId":"00004544"}],
                    "nation":"nation1",
                    "company":"company1",
                    "genre":"genre1",
                    "kmdbUrl":"http://www.kmdb.or.kr/vod/vod_basic.asp?nation=K&p_dataid=01040",
                    "rating":[{"ratingMain":"Y","ratingDate":"19640717","ratingNo":"","ratingGrade":"","releaseDate":"","runtime":""}]]}
```

Here is my Json Data from OKHttp parsing.

Actually There is many same Result 2~3.

**I want to parsing key name "title", "directorNm", "nation", "company", "ratingGrade" and set Model class.**

**How to parsing multiple Json Object and Array with Gson into Model class?**

I'm finally going to use the recyclerview with model class.

If you tell me how to parsing "title" and "directorNm", I can do to rest.

For reference, I am using a AsyncTask, OKHttp, Gson etc.

If you don't understand my question or need code, please comment!

I need your help vigorously.

Comment: Have u try with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: In addition, I'm use AsyncTask. how to parsing in doInBackground and return onPostExecute?

Comment: @NileshRathod
I will try that right now!

Comment: @NileshRathod My pojo class is right, but I don't kow, how to set values into model at Android Activity

Comment: You can use Gson https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 0):

Here I am sharing the code settting response from Model(Pojo Class)

```
public void getResponse(JSONObject jsonObject){
    try {
        JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(jsonObject.toString());

        JSONArray jsonArray = responseJson.getJSONArray("heroes");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                //getting the json object of the particular index inside the array
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                YourPojoClass pojoObject = new YourPojoClass();

                pojoObject.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                pojoObject.setImageurl(jsonObject.getString("imageurl"));

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can put this function in your onPostExecute method of asynchTask